# Конвертация строки с датой

Tags: java, android, дата, время

В локальной базе данных приложения android хранится время в таком формате строки: Wed, 12 Feb 2020 8:52:39 GMT. 
Мне нужно вывести в формате: 12.02.2020 8:52:39, чтобы время/дата зависeли от часового пояса, выставленного в настройках системы. Подскажите как правильно конвертировать, пожалуйста.

**После всех проб, ошибок и помощи я всё-же смог сделать конвертацию.**

```
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat( "EEE, dd MMM yyyy H:mm:ss zzz", Locale.US);

        try {
            Date date = df.parse("Wed, 12 Feb 2020 12:52:39 GMT");

            SimpleDateFormat dfout = new SimpleDateFormat( "dd.MM.yyyy H:mm:ss");
            String res = dfout.format(date);
            viewHolder.txtDATE.setText(res);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: а кто сохраняет дату в бд в таком формате "Wed, 12 Feb 2020 8:52:39 GMT." ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Момент первый: лучше не хранить дату с использованием текста. Храните в виде "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss" или вообще unixtime-ом. Это правда удобней, и в базе можно запросы с фильтрацией по дате делать, и парсить проще. Конкретно в вашем случае должно сработать что-то такое:

```
ZonedDateTime.parse("Wed, 12 Feb 2020 8:52:39 GMT").format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "d MM YYYY HH:mm:ss"))
```

Или переведем в Data

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat( "E, dd MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss z");
Date date = df.parse("Wed, 12 Feb 2020 8:52:39 GMT");
SimpleDateFormat dfout = new SimpleDateFormat( "d MM YYYY HH:mm:ss");
String res = dfout.format(date);
```

Comment: Дату я загружаю через xml-парсер. Ещё не разобрался как правильно конвертировать дату, по этому пока что храню в таком виде.

Comment: данный метод работает с версии Android O(8.1). Мне нужна минимальная версия 4.0.3.

Comment: Добавил альтернативный вариант, который должен работать на 4

Comment: Теперь ошибка выпадает на строке     date = df.parse("Wed, 12 Feb 2020 8:52:39 GMT");

Comment: Ошибку надо указывать, а то мало ли на что он там ругается. Предположу, что там есть еще какой-нибудь параметр, о котором я забыл

Comment: W/System.err: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Wed, 12 Feb 2020 8:52:39 GMT"

Comment: Наверное я ошибся в описании паттерна. Перепроверить не смогу, к сожалению, в ближайшее время, Можете попробовать сами разобраться с правилами их создания

Comment: Android studio заставляет строке     date = df.parse("Wed, 12 Feb 2020 8:52:39 GMT") заносить в try/catch. Это на что-то влияет?

Comment: Этот метод может выбросить исключение. Если метод может его выбросить, то вы обязаны либо отловить его через try, либо сделать метод, в котором этот исключение бросающий метод вызывается, тоже бросающим исключение(после параметров добавляем throws Exception)

Comment: Всё. Разобрался. Тестил на Android 10 все паттерны, которые мог. Второй вариант выдавал ошибку. Попробовал на 4.0.3- всё заработало. Сейчас попробую оба  варианта вставить для разных версий. Паттерн взял из второго ответа.

Answer (score 2):

```
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .parseCaseSensitive()
            .appendPattern("EEE, dd MMM yyyy H:mm:ss zzz")
            .toFormatter();

        DateTimeFormatter toFormat = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .parseCaseSensitive()
            .appendPattern("dd.MM.yyyy H:mm:ss")
            .toFormatter();

        ZonedDateTime time = LocalDateTime.parse("Wed, 12 Feb 2020 8:52:39 GMT", formatter)
            .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());

        String format = time.format(toFormat);
        System.out.println(format);
```

У `DateTimeFormatter` очень хорошая [документация](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) советую "пройтись" по-нему . В этом коде мы просто получаем `LocalDateTime` от нашей даты а потом `ZonedDateTime` добавляя зону, которая настроен в системе. Ну а в конце просто формат в строку в том паттерне который вам нужен.

Comment: Благодарю за ваш ответ. К сожалению это не помогло. Данный метод работает с версии Android O (8.1). Минимальная версия, которая мне нужна-4.0.3. А так-же выпадает ошибка в строке   ZonedDateTime time = LocalDateTime.parse("Wed, 12 Feb 2020 8:52:39 GMT", formatter)

Comment: Дату я загружаю через xml-парсер. Ещё не разобрался как правильно конвертировать дату, по этому пока что храню в таком виде.

Comment: Опираясь на ответ @Спицко-Дмитрий . `SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz");
        Date date = df.parse("Wed, 12 Feb 2020 8:52:39 GMT");
        SimpleDateFormat dfout = new SimpleDateFormat( "d MM yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        dfout.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()));
        String res = dfout.format(date);`  не забудьте добавить `TimeZone`